# PHP: get last 6 months in format month year

Tags: php, date, format

Is there a way in PHP to get the current and the previous 5 months in the following format?

```
April 2014
March 2014
February 2014
January 2014
December 2013
November 2013
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you tried following:

```
<?php
echo date('F, Y');
for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
  echo date(', F Y', strtotime("-$i month"));
}
```

Let me know, if this wont work.

Comment: This is nice. this displays the months in descending order (latest month till the past 6 months). How to do this to display in ascending order?

Comment: be careful when using this solution.
expl: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50623376/7057993

Comment: Can confirm. IT'S BUGGY. PLEASE DON'T USE THIS

Answer (score 9):

Do not use:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++) {
  echo date('F Y', strtotime(-$i . 'month'));
}
// With date e.g.: "May, 31", outputs:
// May, 2018, May 2018, March 2018, March 2018, January 2018, December 2017
```

You can fix it by:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++) {
  echo date('F Y', strtotime('last day of ' . -$i . 'month'));
}
```

Or better use DateTime, e.g.:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('first day of this month');
for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
    echo $dateTime->format('F Y');
    $dateTime->modify('-1 month');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
for ($j = 0; $j <= 5; $j++) {
    echo date("F Y", strtotime(" -$j month"));
}
```

Comment: your missing the current date. $j should be at 0 to get today.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) Object as

```
$start = new DateTime('first day of this month - 6 months');
$end   = new DateTime('last month');
$interval  = new DateInterval('P1M'); // http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

$date_period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
$months = array();
foreach($date_period as $dates) {
  array_push($months, $dates->format('F').' '.$dates->format('Y'));
}

print_r($months);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [strtotime](https://www.php.net/strtotime) and [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
for( $i = 0; $i <= 5 ; $i++) {
     print date("F Y", strtotime("-".$i." month"))."\n";
}
```

to achieve another formats for date look PHP date format [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
for ($i =0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $months[] = date("F Y", strtotime( date( 'Y-m-01' )." -$i months"));
}

print_r($months)
?>
```

Try This..

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
   $months[] = date("M-y", strtotime( date( 'Y-m-01' )." -$i months"));
}
print_r($months);
```

Comment: When answering an older question with existing answers it is useful to explain what new features your answer includes. Code only answers without some explanation are  unlikely to be upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

```
@php
   for($i=0; $i<=5; $i++) {
     $last_six_months[] =date("Y-m-d", strtotime( date( 'Y-m-01' )." -$i months"));
   }
    $last_six_months = array_reverse($last_six_months); // If you want to reverse...
@endphp

next >>>

 @foreach($last_six_months as $key => $row)
     <span>{{date('F Y',strtotime($row))}}</span>
 @endforeach
```