# Getting the latest 6 months in ascending order

Tags: php

**Objective:** To have the months display in a graph in ascending order [eg; Dec 2018, Jan 2019, Feb 2019]

I tried the solution here:

[PHP: get last 6 months in format month year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784894/php-get-last-6-months-in-format-month-year)

This works well, just that it displays the months in descending order.

So I tried to rewrite that code to display it in ascending order.

Original Code:

```
<?php
echo date('F, Y');
for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
  echo date(', F Y', strtotime("-$i month"));
}
?>
```

This is what I tried:

```
<?php

$sixMonthAgo = date("F Y",strtotime("-5 month")); // To get the month 6 month ago

echo $sixMonthAgo;
for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
  echo date(', F Y', strtotime("-$i month"));
}

?>
```

But I realised that my logic is all wrong here. True enough, I got the 6 month ago month in `$sixMonthAgo`, but my logic of the loop is wrong.

My loop is getting the current date and then subtracting the months accordingly to `i` value. How do I replace that date to the value of $sixMonthAgo.

Something like this: `echo test(', F Y', strtotime("+$i month"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate from high to low. I think this would work.

```
<?php
echo date('F, Y');
for ($i = 5; $i >= 0; $i--) {
  echo date(', F Y', strtotime("-$i month"));
}
?>
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you.